# c minimax using posix threads

Tags: c, dynamic, pthreads, posix, minimax

I am writing program with POSIX threads to find minimax in integer array. My question is how can I determine how many threads do I need to and is it correct to output minimum and maximum inside the thread function? And why do would I need dynamic threads?

Here is my code:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

#define num_of_threads 1
#define size 10

int array[size];

typedef struct st_minimax {
    int min;
    int max;
} minimax;

void *thread_minimax(void* ptr) { //thread is searching
    int i;
    minimax *data;
//    data = (minimax*) malloc(minimax);

    data = (minimax*) ptr;

    data->max = array[0];
    data->min = array[0];

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] > data->max)
            data->max = array[i];
        else if (array[i] < data->min)
            data->min = array[i];
    }

    printf("Thread is calculating...\n");
    printf("Min: %d", data->min);
    printf("Max: %d", data->max);

    pthread_exit(NULL); //exit thread
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    pthread_t worker[num_of_threads];
    minimax data;
    int t;
    int i;
    int ret;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) { //initialize the array
        printf("enter value for %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    for(t=0;t<num_of_threads;t++)
{
    printf("creating threads...%d\n",t);
    ret = pthread_create(&worker[t], 0, thread_minimax, (void*) &data); //creating thread
    sleep(1);
    if (ret) {
        fprintf(stderr, "thread err %d", ret);
        exit(-1);
    }

}
    pthread_exit(NULL); //exit thread
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per conversation with the OP author, `N` (1d) arrays should be created with `M` elements (i.e. `N` rows and `M` columns) and if there are `N` arrays then there should be `N` thread created (for array[0], thread-0). The threads should work on the corresponding array and get the `min` and `max` values for that array.

Here is the code which does that!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* N is the number of threads */
/* also N is the number of arrays */
/* row */
#define N 10 

/* M is the length of each array */
/* column */
#define M 10

/* the 2d array which contains N rows and M columns */
int **matrix;

void display(void)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
        for (j=0 ; j<M ; j++) {
            printf("%3d  ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}

void * thread_handler(void *thread_id)
{
    int *id = (int *) thread_id;
    int i = *id, j; 
    int min = matrix[i][0];
    int max = matrix[i][0];

    for (j=1 ; j<M ; j++) {
        if (matrix[i][j] > max)
            max = matrix[i][j];
        if (matrix[i][j] < min)
            min = matrix[i][j];
    }

    printf("array[%d] min[%d] max[%d]\n", i, min, max);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, ret;
    pthread_t tids[N];
    int ids[N] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    srand(time(NULL));

    matrix = (int **) malloc (sizeof(int *) * N);
    for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++) 
        matrix[i] = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int) * M);

    for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
        for (j=0 ; j<M ; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 500;
        }
    }

    display();

    for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
        printf("Creating thread #%d \n", ids[i]);
        ret = pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, thread_handler, &ids[i]);
        if (ret) {
            printf("unable to create thread! \n");
            exit(-1);
        } 
    }

    for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);     

    for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++) 
        free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

The following is the output:

```
$ gcc dynamic_array_threads.c -lpthread -o dat
$ ./dat 
441  252  474  311  468  435  376  361  273  183  
482   30   99   47   23  361  118  455  233  178  
457  492  346  449   27  344  201  376  153  230  
375   94  482  349  257  451  136  133  164  409  
317  147  291  416   46  167  129   17  474  214  
 47  283  206  393  232   85   90  285  461  243  
 16  188  189  350  389  299  153   25  432  170  
286  101  169  430  369  215  449  350   84  423  
417  131   59  123   25  143   61  467  429  374  
210  297   63  251  499  304   50    5  330  335  
Creating thread #0 
Creating thread #1 
array[0] min[183] max[474]
Creating thread #2 
Creating thread #3 
array[2] min[27] max[492]
Creating thread #4 
array[1] min[23] max[482]
Creating thread #5 
array[4] min[17] max[474]
Creating thread #6 
array[3] min[94] max[482]
array[5] min[47] max[461]
Creating thread #7 
array[6] min[16] max[432]
Creating thread #8 
Creating thread #9 
array[8] min[25] max[467]
array[9] min[5] max[499]
array[7] min[84] max[449]
$
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The `pthread_join()` function waits for the `thread` specified by `thread` to terminate. More on `pthread_join()` can be found in the man pages. `man pthread_join`

Answer (score 1):

1. You'd need to specify your criteria in order to determine how many threads you "need".  As currently written, you only need 1, since the thread scans the whole array.
2. It is OK for a thread to print from a thread; however, if you are trying to find the min & max of a single array, and break up the work amongst multiple threads, then you probably wouldn't want to (instead, have the main process the results from each thread for the overall answer).
3. Not sure what the question is about dynamic arrays and dynamic threads; main can allocate the space for each array dynamically (similar to what you do in the commented out code in your thread); what needs to be more dynamic in your threads?

Comment: for example i need to find min max in 3 different arrays, so i should output min max in main?

Comment: If the computations for the arrays are independent (and it sounds like, from other comments, that they are), you can output the results from the threads.  Although if you did it from main, you could more easily control the order in which the results were produced.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I determine how many threads do I need to

The nature of this problem does not demand any multi-threaded programming.

> is it correct to output minimum and maximum inside the thread function?

There is nothing wrong with this. Its totally based on what you need (in case of `homework`, it is totally depends on what your professor wants!).

> And how could I modify the program to allocate dynamic array and dynamic threads

To allocate arrays dynamically, you can use `malloc()` and to free them, use `free()` as follows

```
int *ptr = NULL;
if ((ptr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * len)) == NULL) {
    printf("unable to allocate memory \n");
    return -1;
}

/* you can use the ptr to read-from/write-to the allocated memory */

free(ptr);
```

And, what do you mean by `dynamic threads`?

OTOH, when I executed your code snippet, I found nothing wrong in that. It just worked fine!

Comment: for example i need to find min max in 3 different arrays, so i should output min max in main?

Comment: @mydreamadsl Ah! you mean to say that you have `n` arrays so that you need to create `n` threads which can return the `min` and `max` values for the corresponding arrays back to the `main`?!

Comment: @mydreamadsl Please check out my new post! .. Its a good question! I tried my level best to answer that! Thanks!